# How to serialize an XNA Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm serializing a data structure to XML using the `IntermediateSerializer` class.  This data structure has an XNA `Rectangle` in it.  The rest of the data structure outputs fine, but the `Rectangle` part outputs as:

```
<Bounds>
  <Location>
    <X>15</X>
    <Y>0</Y>
  </Location>
  <Size>
    <X>16</X>
    <Y>13</Y>
  </Size>
  <X>15</X>
  <Y>0</Y>
  <Width>16</Width>
  <Height>13</Height>
</Bounds>
```

Instead of the condensed form:

```
<Bounds>15 0 16 13</Bounds>
```

Previous experience has shown me that I really want the condensed form so my other program can read in the `Rectangle` correctly.  How do I get the serializer to write it that way?

Comment: Why not write it yourself? It is literrally just 4 values.

Comment: The `Rectangle` is just one part of a larger data structure.  I'm using `IntermediateSerializer.Serialize` to output the whole thing at once.  Tweaking the serializer to get the `Rectangle` right seems more elegant than writing a custom output procedure.

Comment: There's no way to inherit or override `IntermediateSerializer` and there's no way to alter the attributes on `Rectangle`. The simplest options are either to use a different serialiser (i.e. write one yourself, even if it's just an adaptor that treats `Rectangle`s specially), or put up with the horrible verbose xml. I take it your other program does not have access to `IntermediateSerializer`?

Comment: Alas.  The solution I came up with was to change the `Rectangle` in my data structure to a `int[]`.  That one serializes/deserializes in the condensed form I want, and I just have to build the `Rectangle` in the code that does the deserializing.